# jQuery/Javascript seems to stop working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm still learning jQuery (1.6 min) and Javascript, but have been quite pleased with what I have been able to achieve, so far, but this problem has me fooled - i've been looking at it for four hours!

I have the following link on a page contained within a  (for which the id value is 'NorthWest'):-

```
<figure><a href="http://localhost:8888/popup/PFS98394" class="popUpSimple"><img src="http://localhost:8888/98394.jpg" alt="" border="0"></a></figure>
```

which when clicked on, correctly loads content in to a  makes the  visible.  It does not reload the page, simply makes the DIV visible on top of the current content.  The Javascript for doing this uses standard jQuery Fancybox.

All works fine, the DIV can be shown and hidden several times, loading different information on each occasion.  Now there is a IMG button which allows the user to reload the 'NorthWest' DIV with the latest content - when clicked it executes this code:

```
 $(".RefreshThumb").find("a").click(function(){
   $(".RefreshLoader").show();
   $("#NorthWest").load("/refreshdata");
   setTimeout(RefreshHide,1000);
 });
```

The setTimeout line refers to a small graphic (refreshloader) which is momentarily displayed to advise the user that a refresh of the data is taking place.

Now, take out the $("#NorthWest").load etc.. line and all works fine.  Add that line back in, and the popUpSimple link works fine until the IMG button is clicked to refresh the NorthWest DIV, after which the popUpSimple content is loaded as a new page and no longer overlaid - before clicking that the popup overlay works fine no matter how many times you click it.

**EDIT:** I should point out that after clicking on the IMG button to reload the NorthWest DIV it does so successfully, its only when you then click the popUpSimple link that things go wrong!

What have I done wrong?  I'm using Safari and a look at the Web Inspector window after the page has been reloaded rather than loaded into the DIV shows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
```

With a message saying Reference Error: Can't find variable $.

Can anyone point me in the right direction .... please!

Comment: Make sure you are including jQuery above your script.

Comment: Can we see some more of the code? I get the feeling what when you are loading the content you are losing your event listeners

Comment: If you could reproduce the behavior in a live demo such as in http://jsfiddle.net it'd be much easier to reply.

Comment: @orolo - I wondered about that.  But it all works fine to start with.  I added a script include to jQuery in the content file that is loaded with the popupsimple link and everything stopped working! So took it out again!

Comment: @LastRoseStudios - Sure which bit do you want to see more of?  Where do you think I could be losing the event listeners?

Comment: @TIW Ideally the entire page so I have a better idea of what is being called where

Comment: Unfortunately unless we can see all of your code, I doubt anyone here will be able to help you. Please post the entire code, either here, or to http://jsfiddle.net or http://jsbin.com so that we can have a better idea as to what is going on, and the structure of your page

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like an eventlistener issue, Try using `.on('click',function(){}` instead of `.click(function(){}`

Comment: AFAIK, `.on` was introduced in jQuery 1.7. OP states that he's using 1.6, so he would have to use `.live` or `.delegate`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the jquery '$' is being overridden by another JS framework.

Just replace your '$' with 'jQuery' without the single quotes of course. 
You may even try using http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/
you can add this right after you load the jQuery library for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="other_lib.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.noConflict();
  // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks i'll try that, although I'm new to jQuery and still learning the basics, so where you would suggest putting it?  In the .click function? Whereabouts?

Comment: actually just as a test try using jQuery instead of "$" for example:
`jQuery(".RefreshThumb").find("a").click(function(){ jQuery(".RefreshLoader").show(); jQuery("#NorthWest").load("/refreshdata"); setTimeout(RefreshHide,1000); });`

Comment: Ok, I changed the code as you suggested, the same thing happens.  You can show the popUpSimple DIV once, twice, however many times you want WITHOUT clicking the refresh button for the NorthWest DIV and it works perfectly.  Click the refresh button, and then click on the popUpSimple link and the page reloads rather than overlaying :(  Would that suggest its not a conflict??

Comment: It's really hard to say without seeing more of the code. We might be missing a '$' somewhere else where there is a conflict. To rule it out though do you know if that popup script is using another version of jquery or some other framework? Are you using wordpress? if not then my answer won't pertain.

Comment: Hi, no its all hand coded, no wordpress involved.  The popup script all of the above code is on the same HTML (well PHP) page, so its all using the same jQuery framework.  The code that is loaded into the DIV for the popUpSimple link doesn't have any jQuery or Javascript, and neither does the code that is displayed within the NorthWest DIV.

Comment: I've just realised I gave slightly a wrong answer yesterday - the code that is loaded by the popUpSimple link does have jQuery script in it, which again works fine prior to the refresh button being clicked.

Comment: Ok, well its not the JQuery script in the popUpSimple link that is causing the issue - i've just commented it out and run the code again, and all remains the same.

Comment: Are you able to post your code somewhere I could take a look at it? like jsfiddle.com?